# What is the meaning of the expression $\liminf f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, definition

I am a little confused as to what $\liminf f_n$ means for a sequence $f_n$ of functions converging to $f$.  I can not locate a definition anywhere.

Comment: it is defined pointwisely, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The lim inf of a function is defined as 
$$\liminf_{x\to \xi} f(x)= \sup_{a>0} \inf f((\xi-a,\xi+a))$$
I guess they want those definition as the liminf for a converging sequence is the same as the normal limit.

Comment: The OP has the the changing variable to be $f_n$, in your case you have the value passed into the function changing. The OP is asking about the $\liminf$ of a sequence of functions, whereas you are talking about the $\liminf$ of a function at a point, or neighborhood of a point.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can define it using the usual definition of the $\lim \inf$ for each $x$: $ \lim \inf f_n(x)$ is the smallest limit point of the sequence $\{ f_n(x) \}_n$.

Comment: that would be pretty uninteresting, as this would be always equal to $f(x)$, as we said, that $f_n\to f$ pointwise

Comment: well yes if $f_n$ converges pointwise then the $\lim \inf$ is the limit, I don't see why it is uninteresting.

Comment: why would you say liminf if you know that is exactly the same as lim ?

Comment: What is the context? I thought maybe it could have been to prove the pointwise convergence using the $\lim \inf$ because it is always defined (contrary to the limit) or maybe the convergence of the sequence $f_n$ was other than pointwise, I don't know...