# Definition of lim inf $f_n$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having difficulty understanding what $\liminf f_n$ means where $f_n$ is a sequence of functions.  I understand what it means for a sequence of points, just not for a sequence of functions.

Thank you

Comment: I mean it in the sense of Fatou's Lemma.  So I guess that is pointwise.  Does that mean that $g = \liminf f_n$ is defined by $g(x) = \liminf f_n(x)$ for each $x?$

Comment: Yes, this means what you say.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324103/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-expression-liminf-f-n duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the expression $\liminf f_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324103/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-expression-liminf-f-n)

Answer (score 2):

In the context you're looking at: $$\displaystyle \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n = \sup_{n \geq 0} \inf_{m \geq n} f_m$$ pointwise.

In our case, the variable that is changing is the function, if the variable that's changing is the value passed into the function we would have: $$\liminf_{y \to x} f(y) = \sup_{\delta > 0} \inf_{\vert y - x \vert < \delta} f(y).$$